# FreeBSD "Fatal double fault" upon entering ZFS encryption password

Tags: freebsd, system-installation, zfs, kernel-panic

I have just installed FreeBSD 10.1 Release i386 on a new computer.  I pretty much used the standard installer defaults, except I chose ZFS, RAID-Z1, encryption, and encrypted swap, and I did not install ports (it would consistently freeze when installing them).  Installation seemed to go fine.  When I rebooted, it prompted me for the password to decrypt the drive; I entered it, it gave various normal GELI messages, and then:

```
Trying to mount root from zfs:zroot/ROOT/default []...

Fatal double fault:
eip = 0xc186ad12
esp = 0xc7a3ef80
ebp = 0xc7a3f2e0
cpuid = 3; apic id = 03
panic: double fault
cpuid = 3
KDB: stack backtrace:
#0 0xc0b53ed2 at kdb_backtrace+0x52
#1 0xc0b1688f at panic+0x11f
#2 0xc101bedb at dblfault_handler+0xab
```

It then threatened to reboot in 15 seconds unless I pressed a key.  Pressing a key pauses that countdown, but the only option at that point is to press another key to reboot.

I've since rebooted several times, and the exact same thing has happened every time.  I do not know how to proceed.  Any advice would be appreciated.  Thank you.

**EDIT:** Thinking the problem might be related to encryption, I tried the installation over again, the same way except not using encryption (neither the main nor swap).  The exact same problem occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

Switching from i386 to amd64 seems to have resolved the issue (and also the issue of the ports installation freezing).  I originally did not use amd64 because I don't have an AMD processor, but I now see from the documentation that amd64 can be used with certain Intel processors as well, including the one I have.